# Issue with an observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I created an observer to update the product, but it is not entering it.

> config.xml:

```
<cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
    <observers>
        <gestaobox_api>
            <class>Gestaobox_Api_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>SaveStockInventory</method>
            <type>singleton</type>
        </gestaobox_api>
    </observers>
</cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after>
```

> Observer.php:

```
public function SaveStockInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
{
    $id = $event->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

    Mage::log($id, null, "testeStock.log");

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $name = $product->getName();
    $product->setName($name);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: In which parent block is cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after in your xml?

Comment: And what is your class name and what are you extending? You need to show more code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using the reindex. follow the code:

```
public function SaveStockInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
{
    $dados = $event->getEvent()->getItem();
    $idProduct = $dados->getProductId();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($idProduct);
    $name = $product->getName();
    $product->setName($name);

    $product->save();

    $indexcodes = array("cataloginventory_stock");

    //reindex
    foreach ($indexcodes as $index) {
        try {
            $process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode($index);
            $process->reindexEverything();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'dasda.log');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, I update it but you can't see the diference because you set the same product name

```
$name = $product->getName(); // burger1
$product->setName($name); // burger1
```

Try this:

```
public function SaveStockInventory(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
{
    $id = $event->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();
    Mage::log($id, null, "testeStock.log");
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
    $name = "Big tasty burger";
    $product->setName($name);
    $product->save();
}
```